# How can I switch a running website to PWA

Tags: javascript, html, web, progressive-web-apps

Is there a way to switch a running website to PWA (without reloading the website)? This option is available on my browsers. For example, on Chrome:
[image]

Now I was wondering if there was a way for me to do this programmatically?

Thanks

Comment: is your website written as a PWA? you can't just install a website as a PWA, unless it is written as a PWA

Comment: @JaromandaX yes my website is a PWA.

Comment: If someone has installed the pwa, at least in chrome on android, I'm sure it asks if you want to open the app. Even firefox on android does this. But, the pwa would necessarily load, so reload isn't even in the equation

Comment: @JaromandaX I am not sure if you understand the question. It does ask me to open the app, but only when I click on the button I highlighted in the screenshot above. But how do I achieve this without the default browser button? Any way to do this in Javascript?

Comment: I understand. But what you want is not possible. You can't interact with the browser chrome. Not Chrome, chrome. I.e. the stuff out of reach of Web pages

Comment: @JaromandaX thanks for clearing that out. I did not have much hopes for it anyway